# How to create intro slides in jQuery mobile for phoneGap application?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I would like to create a tutorial at the start of my application that shows once when the user downloads the app. I'm not sure of the name of this design, but it allows the user to slide 3-5 screens and get a sense of how to use the app they downloaded (see image below). Is it possible to do this in jQuery mobile? I took a look at the widgets and API documentation, but am not sure.

[image]

Comment: You can use a carousel/slider plugin such as Owl Carousel: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/. I have used is successfully within a jQuery Mobile project.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Is it literally plug and play?

Comment: Pretty much. Here is a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/pkesj9s9/

Comment: Very cool. How come you didn't need to specify jQuery mobile as a plugin? How did it recognize keywords like data-role and data-theme?

Comment: I did, look at the external resources. jQuery, jQuery Mobile, and the OWL css and js

Comment: I see it now! How do you link the external resources, you just copy the whole code?

Comment: Are you talking about jsFiddle? You just provide a link to an online url of the file.